# Multiply Nested IF in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, nested-if

I'm trying to create a "Nested If" on Google Sheets. I've 3 columns, one with neighborhoods (Manhattan, Queens, Staten Island, Bronx, Brooklyn), one with room type (Private room, Entire apt/home, Shared room) and one with price (in $).
I need to make something like this:

*If neighborhood is "Brooklyn" and room_type is "Private room", write "alto" in the cell, else write "basso"*

I made this with this formula and it works perfectly:

```
=IF(AND(E2:E48896 = "Brooklyn"; J2:J48896 = "Private room");IF(K2:K48896 > 150;"alto"; "basso"))
```

But now I have to increase this formula, because I want to do the same thing on the other room type for Brooklyn
(so Brooklyn-->Entire apt--> price > 180; Brooklyn -->Shared room --> price > 80) and increase this for every neighborhood.

So I just basically want to join all this formulas together and put it in inside ad "ARRAYFORMULA" so it automatically works in all my column.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

converted to AF it would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((E2:E48896 = "Brooklyn")*(J2:J48896 = "Private room"); 
 IF(K2:K48896 > 150; "alto"; "basso")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I've increase my formula and it works perfectly. The current formula is

```
 =IF(AND(E3:E48897 = "Brooklyn"; J3:J48897 = "Private room");IF(K3:K48897 > 150;"alto"; "basso");
IF(AND(E3:E48897 = "Brooklyn"; J3:J48897 = "Entire home/apt");IF(K3:K48897 > 180;"alto"; "basso");
IF(AND(E3:E48897 = "Brooklyn"; J3:J48897 = "Shared room");IF(K3:K48897 > 80;"alto"; "basso");
IF(AND(E3:E48897 = "Manhattan"; J3:J48897 = "Entire home/apt");IF(K3:K48897 > 300;"alto"; "basso");
IF(AND(E3:E48897 = "Manhattan"; J3:J48897 = "Private room");IF(K3:K48897 > 200;"alto"; "basso");
IF(AND(E3:E48897 = "Manhattan"; J3:J48897 = "Shared room");IF(K3:K48897 > 140;"alto";"basso");
SE(E(E3:E48897 = "Queens"; J3:J48897 = "Private room");SE(K3:K48897 > 100;"alto";"basso");
SE(E(E3:E48897 = "Queens"; J3:J48897 = "Entire home/apt");SE(K3:K48897 > 130;"alto";"basso");
SE(E(E3:E48897 = "Queens"; J3:J48897 = "Shared room");SE(K3:K48897 > 80;"alto";"basso");
SE(E(E3:E48897 = "Bronx"; J3:J48897 = "Private room");SE(K3:K48897 > 80;"alto";"basso");
SE(E(E3:E48897 = "Bronx"; J3:J48897 = "Entire home/apt");SE(K3:K48897 > 100;"alto";"basso");
SE(E(E3:E48897 = "Bronx"; J3:J48897 = "Shared room");SE(K3:K48897 > 50;"alto";"basso");
SE(E(E3:E48897 = "Staten Island"; J3:J48897 = "Private room");SE(K3:K48897 > 110;"alto";"basso");
SE(E(E3:E48897 = "Staten Island"; J3:J48897 = "Entire home/apt");SE(K3:K48897 > 160;"alto";"basso");
SE(E(E3:E48897 = "Staten Island"; J3:J48897 = "Shared room");SE(K3:K48897 > 70;"alto";"basso"))))))))))))))))
```

But then, when I try to put all this code inside an =ARRAYFORMULA(), it returns FALSE value just for the first cell of the column.
How can I fix it and made all the formula run for all the column?